# Can I conditionally Skip test case and show testcase status as 'skip' with 'pass' and 'fail' in report?

Tags: automation, robotframework

Trying to skip execution on condition but getting an error "No keyword with name 'Skip Execution' found".

I want to decide whether to execute a test case based on input data. I tried using tags but tags are not working dynamically, I want the conditional test case execution by the flag set in excel sheet. 
[ExcelInput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IVo7S.png)

Is it possible to add test case status as 'skip' along with 'pass' and 'fail' in test case report as [ReportWithSkipStatus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xlf7E.png) at https://github.com/robotframework/robotframework/issues/2087#issuecomment-148559931?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to skip test case in Robot framework using keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34508000/how-to-skip-test-case-in-robot-framework-using-keyword)

Comment: The hottest topic in RF a month ago :) - https://github.com/robotframework/robotframework/issues/2087

Comment: Why do you think there is a "skip execution" keyword? It's not mentioned in any documentation. Are you using a third party library with that keyword?

Comment: @JustinWilkins thanks, but I need to check execution flag at beginning of test case, and if execution flag is "No", then i need to fail test case without affecting execution of other cases can u suggest something?

Comment: @omi27 your comment has the tone "I want to **fail** cases conditionally", which is a different question, and we'l within the capabilities of the framework. If I have understood you correct, put that as a new question.

Comment: Thanks, @TodorMinakov tried github.com/robotframework/robotframework/issues/2087 but facing same issue of 'Skip Execution' is there any other way?

Comment: @BryanOakley No i am not using third party library trying solution explained at github.com/robotframework/robotframework/issues/2087

Comment: What's the solution there you tried? That thread is endless, heavily diluted and with no resolution in sight.

Comment: thanks, @TodorMinakov i tried this one https://github.com/robotframework/robotframework/issues/2087#issuecomment-148559931

Comment: That's a PR in a branch, from 3 years ago, that has not made it to mainline. That is **not available in the framework** - as you are seeing from the failures when you tried using it. If that is the only premise for your question, I'd suggest for you to close it.

Comment: Just to be clear: are you saying that you're using a fork of robot framework that includes the pull request associated with that issue?

Comment: @BryanOakley if that was the case, the exception would be different, the keyword would be in scope in that branch'es code. Thus I think OP just took the code sample in the discussion as something available, and tried using it. This just adds a data point `skip` is much needed addition to the framework...

Comment: @TodorMinakov please find https://github.com/robotframework/robotframework/issues/2087#issuecomment-148559931 report there is status 'SKIP' with pass and fail status, I guess keyword 'Skip' or 'Skip Execution' is descoped from the library can you please giude? i am new to robot framework

Comment: @omi27 what you are reading/the link you've given, is a feature request - which is not implemented nor available yet. This keyword `Skip Test` and the surrounding functionally does not exist, and you can't use it yet. Sorry ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: ohh!! @TodorMinakov thanks (:

Answer (score 0):

There's a built in keyword for this called

```
pass execution if
```

You determine your input data and message you want to send if the condition is true and "skips" the current test, or other keywords after.
http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Pass%20Execution%20If

Comment: thanks, but I need to check execution flag at beginning of test case, and if execution flag is "No", then i need to fail test case without affecting execution of other cases can u suggest something?